# OOB Check Update Available

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I need to check , Is the update available but don't need to download.

How can I check this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this unfortunately in Silverlight 4.0.  You would need to create some type of WCF Service which could read the XAP Manifest then report back.  If you check for a new update for your OOB app it will download the update.